# Android layout_behavior does not work on included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

If I have a layout like so, with the layout_behavior defined on the FloatingActionsMenu, everything works OK (the behavior is used):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>

    <me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorAccentDark"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        app:layout_behavior=".views.ActionMenuBehavior"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**however**, if I try to define it like so, with the FloatingActionsMenu code extracted to its own layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>

    <me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/floating_action_menu"
        app:layout_behavior=".views.ActionMenuBehavior">
    </include>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The behavior is not called. It also is not called if I move the `app:layout_behavior` to within the extracted out FloatingActionsMenu layout.

**Is there a way to use** `app:layout_behavior` **on an included layout?**

Comment: Well, it won't work if it's on the `<include>`. Are you sure it doesn't work when you put it directly on the `<FloatingActionButton>`? Did you try cleaning/rebuilding after you moved it there?

Comment: @MikeM. yes, I just tried it again to make sure. Putting it directly within the floating_action_menu layout has no affect when it is included.

Comment: Er, yeah, I meant `Menu`, not `Button`. Anyhoo, is the included layout just the `FloatingActionsMenu`, or do you have it inside some sort of `ViewGroup`?

Comment: @MikeM. It's just the `FloatingActionsMenu`. Nothing else.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Hi Kevin, could you get it to work? I am facing the same problem where behaviour  has no effect on the included layout.